# How to Save All stderr Logs Into File When Using Docker Compose Locally

Tags: php, docker, nginx, logging, docker-compose

I'm working with a Docker Compose file that spins up a container running WordPress, php-fpm, and nginx.

Within my WordPress configuration, I'm setting `error_log` to write to a file. I have confirmed this is getting set correctly and that the `php.ini` value is correct. However, when I run my application, all of my logs are just getting spit into the terminal and NOT my `debug.log` file. These logs look like this:

```
  WARNING: [pool www] child 41 said into stderr:
```

How can I override whatever's controlling this so that I can have these logs written to a FILE instead of just the terminal?

Thanks & let me know if you need further details.

Comment: can you give some more details? e,g, when you say "spit into the terminal' do you mean the container terminal or terminal from which you started docker-compose. Did you have a look at the -d option of docker-compose up?

Comment: also: how did you confirm that your nginx/wordpress/php settings are correct?